# access to array elements from different function but same class

Tags: c++, arrays, function, class

I have class that contains some functions with an array. One of them called pick, this function does not has an array but i want to display array element  from other function, once i write code to display array element i can not get the element, although the code work and if i add normal text it will display but can not display array elements, i will attach the code below:

## Note i did not attache full code only important parts

```
#include <iostream>
#include<stdlib.h>

#include <string>


using namespace std;

// global variable
string  plantType;
int temperatures ;
string water; 
string sunExposure; 
bool pet;
string plant1,plant2,plant3;

class inside{
public:

void low(){
    string plant1 [3]={"Snake plant","Spider plant","Aloe Vera plant"};
    for(int i =0; i<3; i++){
        cout << "* "<< plant1[i]<<endl;
    }

}
void medium(){
    string plant2 [5]={"Pothos plant","Dracaena plant","ZZ plant","Rubber plant","Philodendron Green plant"};
  for(int i =0; i<5; i++){
        cout << "* "<< plant2[i]<<endl;

}
}
void high(){
    string plant3 [2]={"Bird’s Nest Fern plant","Peace Lily plant"};
     for(int i =0; i<2; i++){
        cout << "* "<< plant3[i]<<endl;

}
}

void pick(){
    cout <<"Best choice for you is: ";



    if (temperatures >= 13 && temperatures <=29 ){

        if(water=="low"){


            if(sunExposure=="fully"){
             cout<<"test"<<endl;
                if(pet==true){
                    cout<<plant1[1]<<endl; //this line cannot be executed 
                  
                }
            }
        }}}

int main(){
cout <<"Where do you want to grow the plant (inside), or (outside)"<<endl;
        cin>>grow;



        if (grow == "inside"){
                //inside home



     cout<<endl<<"inside"<<endl;
     cout<<"Enter the Temperature in (Celsius scale 13-29)"<<endl;
     cin>>temperatures;
     cout<<"Enter water level (low - medium - high)"<<endl;
     cin>>water;
     cout<<"Enter Sun Exposure (fully - partly - shady)"<<endl;
     cin>>sunExposure;
     cout<<"Do you have pet (true or false)? "<<endl;
     cin>>pet;


        inside inside;
        inside.pick();
        }
}
```

Comment: Maybe the arrays should be members instead of local variables inside the member functions.

Comment: There is a `string plant1` at the global level and a `string plant1[3]` inside `low`. The only `plant1` visible to code outside the `low` function is the global `string plant1` so that's what `pick` sees. And since the global `plant1` is an empty string at that point, accessing its 2nd character `plant1[1]` invokes UB (undefined behavior).

Comment: "_**Note i did not attache full code only important parts**_" - When making such a decision you could consult the help pages on SO instead.

Answer (score 0):

The string variables `plant1[3]`, `plant2[3]` & `plant3[3]` are only visible to `low()`, `medium()`, `high()` but they're not for each other. For example, you're something trying to access a locally declared variable of `foo()` function in `bar()` function, which is impossible.

Secondly, you're trying to access `plant1[3]` data member in `pick()` but compiler doesn't know where you've actually defined those three plants' name outside of that function, just it knows `plant1` variable with no arrays which is declared in the private section of the class. Hence, there's a good chance your code will get fail.

Rather you could just declare the same thing in this way:

```
class inside {
    std::string plants1[3] = {"...", ...}; // these variables are
    std::string plants2[3] = {"...", ...}; // only visible inside the
    std::string plants3[3] = {"...", ...}; // class member functions
    .
    .
}
```

And after that, you'll get the line executed successfully.